# Get nodes from responseText using xpath

Tags: ajax, xpath, opera, xmlhttprequest

I want to get all the div elements from a website, using xpath. I'm using Opera 11.50. Cross site xhr works because this is an extension (and responseText gets the right content, and I can say getElementsByTagName('div'), but I need to use xpath). Please help.

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','http://www.msn.com',true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

        //first try
        var root = this.responseXML;
        var nodes = root.selectNodes('//div'); //nodes.length = 0 !!


        //second
        var doc = xhr.responseXML;
        var divs = doc.evaluate( '//div', doc, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
        // divs.snapshotLength = 0 ...    


    }
}
```

Comment: You are facing a namespace issue. Please include the first few lines from the server response XML.

Comment: It's a normal XHTML document, but how do I specifiy the html namespace ?

Comment: Are you sure `responseXML` is populated at all? I would expect the content type of 'http://www.msn.com/' to be text/html and in that case I don't think responseXML is populated. Does `root.selectNodes("//*")` select anything? If not all you could do is take responseText and parse it with your own code e.g. `var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'application/xml');`. Then to use XPath 1.0 against you need to use `doc.evaluate('//xhtml:div', doc, function (pref) { if (pref === 'xhtml') return 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; else return null; }, ..., null)`

Comment: root.selectNodes("//*").length return 1235 nodes

Comment: Well then it is a namespace issue. I guess doing `var nodes = this.responseXML.selectNodes('//xhtml:div', function (prefix) { if (prefix === 'xhtml') return 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; else return null; })` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it worked :). I had no idea on how to register the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

> Well then it is a namespace issue. I guess doing

```
var nodes = this.responseXML.selectNodes('//xhtml:div', function (prefix) { if (prefix === 'xhtml') return 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; else return null; })
```

> should work